# How to target all except for one output in sway-output?

Tags: linux, bash, display, sway

I am writing a bash script to disable all monitors except for the main one.

My current script is:

```
swaymsg output "*" disable
swaymsg output eDP-1 enable pos 0 0 res 3840x2400
```

But it disables all monitors for a few seconds before turning on the main screen.

I am trying to reverse the commands as such:

```
swaymsg output eDP-1 enable pos 0 0 res 3840x2400
swaymsg output "* \ eDP-1" disable
```

To keep the main display on, while turning off any other display, whichever is available.

Is there a way to target **All except some** displays in sway output?